# Arduino + IMU vs ArduIMU

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, robotics

I am working on a UAV and we are currently exploring inertial measurement units or IMUs. The two options that we have come across are:

- Using an Arduino Uno and a 9 DOF IMU like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10724)
- Using an ArduIMU chip like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11055)

Ignoring the cost aspect and assuming the same microprocessor on board, what would be the pros and cons of either of these approaches?

Keep in mind that performance is very important for a UAV controller as ESCs require 60 Hz or higher refresh rates for stable flight.

Answer (score 2):

**Weight:** marginal as the difference between one board (with everything on it) and two boards (Uno plus DOF) may be - for model airplanes every bit counts.

**Size:** the traditional "Uno" is much larger than the ArduIMU integrated boards.

**Power:** the integrated board PROBABLY will use less and thus get away with a smaller (lighter) battery.